# UIDataDetectorTypeAddress for European addresses

Tags: ios, iphone, hyperlink, uitextview

I need to get iOS to automatically recognize addresses outside the phone's locale in a UITextView (or similar text view).

1. It needs to automatically detect the address because the UITextView could hold a variety of different things – sometimes addresses, sometimes dates, sometimes plain old text (that is, I can't just assume that the text will always be an address, so I can't just use attributed text or a tap recognizer to bounce the user to maps).
2. It needs to be outside the phone's locale because the target market for this app is American students studying abroad in a certain european city. Most of the students will have their phones in US locale, but the addresses will all be european.

Fact #1 above led me to try to use `UIDataDetectorTypeAddress`. Unfortunately, the phone won't recognize addresses in a european format **unless the phone has a european locale installed**. On my vanilla simulator, it won't recognize the addresses; on my phone that has the German language installed along with keyboards etc, it *will* recognize the addresses.

**How can I tell iOS to detect european addresses in this text view?**